# Dask groupby date performance

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Given the following dask dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

N = int(1e4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(N, 3), columns=list('abc'),
                 index=pd.date_range(datetime.now(), periods=N, freq='1min'))
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.date)

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=5)
ddf
```

and this slow function:

```
def f(grp, M=5):
    #A slow function
    x = 0
    for n in range(M):
        for idx1, row in grp[list('abc')].items():
            for idx2, v in row.items():
                x += v
    return x
```

I am surprised that pandas is faster than dask for a groupby + aggregate operation, e.g.:

```
%%timeit
res = ddf.groupby('dt').apply(f).compute()
#310 ms ± 3.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

versus:

```
%%timeit
res = df.groupby('dt').apply(f)
#149 ms ± 3.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Am I missing something here? I thought that dask would parallelize this computation? My real use case has millions of rows and my aggregation function is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

When data fit in memory `pandas` is faster than `dask`. I'm wondering which version of `dask` are you using because if you don't declare your metadata for the apply it should return a warning. (Your question is edited and I added metadata).

You could try to run these experiments for a bigger `N`, using a different number of partitions and using multiprocessing.

```
%%timeit -n10
dask <= 0.17.5
res = ddf.groupby('dt').apply(f, meta=('x', 'f8'))\
         .compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)



%%timeit -n10
dask >= 0.18.0
res = ddf.groupby('dt').apply(f, meta=('x', 'f8'))\
         .compute(scheduler='processes')
```

For `N=int(1e5)` and `npartitions=4` on my laptop the `dask` version is faster than the `pandas` one. The next step would be try to improve your function `f`.